# What do you call a Celebration at work?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Just before Christmas or New Years (and maybe some other holidays), companies organise a party for their workers. What do you call a thing like that?

In Russia it is so common that they have a special word for that. Sounds totally like a loanword from English — ‘Korporativ’ (noun) — because the Russian words don't have this word-formation, we don't even use the root ‘corporate’ unless it's very business-y.

Why I am asking this is because I can't look it up in a dictionary, that word 'korporativ' is not in dictionaries yet. And I hope it won't be. But really for now there is no other proper way to call a party like that.

PS Not necessarily a Single word

Comment: *holiday party*, *Christmas party*, *company party*, *work holiday party*, *holiday event*. I could use *corporate party* in a pinch, but I really would not. (It might be the case the only reason "Corporate Party" is in my vocabulary at all is that it's a feature in "Spyfall", the card game created by Ukrainian game designer Alexandr Ushan.)

Answer (score 6):

*Office party*, *work party*, or even *work's "do"*...to add to the list given by Mike Graham.

A corporate event isn't likely to be one put on for employees. It's more likely to be for clients or for a specific business purpose like the launch of a new product. For example, *corporate hospitality* at a sporting or cultural event.

Comment: Yeah, "office party" would be most common in the US, for office workers.  I'm not aware of a strongly favored term for parties for, eg, factory workers or truck drivers, though "company party" is likely used.